# How do I merge rows with the same name?

Tags: r

I would like to merge the rows of the following dataset:

| G Name | "2" |
| --- | --- |
| T | .432 |
| T | .324 |
| M | .234 |
| M | 1 |
| T | .2323 |
| M | 3 |

To look something like this:

| T | M |
| --- | --- |
| .432 | .234 |
| .324 | 1 |
| .2323 | 3 |

I am trying to use the function compare_means to compare the means of T and M, and I believe it will be easier if I aggregate the rows and switch them to columns.

I have used the following:
`dcast(setDT(df), rowid("T")~"M", value.var = '2')`

but am getting this error:

`Error in vapply(X = x, FUN = fun, ..., FUN.VALUE = NA_character_, USE.NAMES = use.names) :  values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0`

> dput(hail2)
> structure(list(`Gene Name` = c("T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T",
> "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M",
> "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M",
> "M"), `2` = c(-0.340173974, 0.245669254, -0.84014903, -0.00220433,
> 0.426648225, 0.417313044, -1.694116111, 0.369440022, 0.56017152,
> -0.61751912, 0.991865167, -1.230882561, -0.730692965, -1.390778898,
> -2.307678187, 0.7043569, -0.873660526, -0.156732349, -1.317427996,
> -0.321818456, -0.11328877, -0.566162981, 0.851214845, -0.187538995,
> 0.872610657, 0.521926485, 0.087866216, 0.234063307, -1.264073699,
> -1.479181036, 1.11413493, -0.016744905, 0.341893958, -0.70268888,
> 0.705940068, -0.759266751, -1.546470032, -0.448358699, -1.260788179,
> -0.673042739, -1.656851943, -0.10892052, -0.795694424, -1.724939861,
> 0.443198534, 1.484073407, -0.835276952, -1.14552469, -0.583955313,
> 0.236862436, 0.263678086, -0.386066977, 0.292269832, -0.84902645,
> 0.044806791, -0.24445013, -0.778632167, 0.951980883, -1.274003666,
> 0.785260639, 0.174794377, -0.769792542, -0.613625551, -0.767829253,
> -1.916481034, -0.783728396, 0.762075891, -0.251291106, 0.993183799,
> 0.187930962, -0.207332266, -1.388477104, 0.308768593, -0.942664173,
> -1.574523648, -1.191292012, -0.522918092, 1.14027982, -0.528421561,
> 1.155780944, -0.037023427, 0.86219234, -0.930682448, -0.180199526,
> -1.126426403, 1.309388661, 0.686231729, 0.650928801, 0.872389066,
> -0.910322295, -1.852693711, 0.510401186, -1.293462321, -0.08486193,
> -1.450561306, -2.575611098, -2.406079408, -0.202916786, 1.766477778,
> 0.348795027, -0.807151243, -0.89230413, 0.249561804, 0.950624086,
> -0.78972385, 0.962898935, 0.919771998, 2.016699997, 1.306770674,
> -0.751828218, -0.254508541, 0.446086963, -0.2156109, 2.579921158,
> -0.366809073, 0.242198147, -0.028855322, 0.180170158, -0.432030157,
> -0.972454965, 0.064964204, -0.276896274, 0.500969879, 0.766199853,
> 1.484436271, -0.039060321, 1.18119942, -0.072003762, 0.023843108,
> 1.316741538, 0.278198508, -2.928224118, -0.850728959, -1.593251505,
> -1.133376868, -0.737775913, -2.22440729, -3.328806827, -2.165898163,
> -1.291183927, -1.950874277, -2.24053192, -2.802811075, -0.539969438,
> -1.838112195, -1.167517609, -1.724287351, 0.09451908, -1.103821823,
> -1.293469048)), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = c("data.table",
> "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f9e660102e0>)

I appreciate any and all advice!

Comment: Using `data.table` you can do `dcast(setDT(df), rowid(col1)~col1, value.var = 'col2')`  where `df` is your dataframe and `col1` and `col2` are two column names.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for your response. I am not familiar with those functions. Here is what I am trying: 

dcast(setDT(df), rowid(col1)~col1), value.var = 'col2')

This doesn't seem to be correct, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @RonakShah I have attempted the following

`dcast(setDT(df), 
      "G Name" ~ rowid(GName, prefix = "T", "M"), 
      value.var = "2")`

and got the following:

`Error: unexpected symbol in:
"dcast(setDT(df), 
      "G Name" ~ rowid(G Name"
>       value.var = "2")
Error: unexpected ')' in "      value.var = "2")`

Comment: Provide your data using `dput` i.e `dput(df)`

Comment: @RonakShah I have included my data using dput